# Why do custom searches list posts with my ignored tags?

Tags: support, search, tag-search, ignored-tags

When I do not search (just list) or search for just tags (like [[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) the results filter out those posts which contain my ignored tags. And I happen have a lot of ignored tags.

But when I search with a keyword (like [[java] image](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+image)) the results contain all posts matching this, including those posts which contain my ignored tags. I also notice the URL changes from `/questions/tagged/...` to `/search?q=...`

How can I search with both tags and keywords and hide posts which contain my ignored tags?

Comment: Intuitively that would be a feature, practically that is not at all the way it is implemented.  These are disconnected sub-systems, especially the horsepower needed to select questions based on each individual user's tagging preferences and do so at a rate of thousands of page views per second is substantial.  Last I looked they used two dedicated big-iron machines (aka the "tagging engines") that do nothing but make these selections.

Comment: Couldn't it just be client-side scripted? I can imagine a greasemonkey script that hides the result tiles if it contains certain tags. I don't know how to code for greasemonkey so it's not up to me.